# Compare three dataframes in Python pandas with duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare a dataframe with two other data frames and add new column if the entry is present.

EG. 
**Base_df**-
**|  Key   |   A  |  B  |**
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b2 |
|  key2  |  a2  |  b2 |

**df_2**-
**|  Key   |   A  |  B  |**
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |

**df_3**-
**|  Key   |   A  |  B  |**
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b2 |
|  key2  |  a2  |  b2 |

Output should be-
**OutputBase_df**-
**|  Key   |   A  |  B  |  df2  |  df3  |**
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |  1  |  1  |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b1 |  1  |  0  |
|  key1  |  a1  |  b2 |  0  |  1  |
|  key2  |  a2  |  b2 |  0  |  1  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` all item into one , then we using `isin` , `cumcount` is to create the identical key for duplicate

```
s1=df1.apply(','.join,1)
s2=df2.apply(','.join,1)
s3=df3.apply(','.join,1)
s1=s1+','+s1.groupby(s1).cumcount().astype(str)
s2=s2+','+s2.groupby(s2).cumcount().astype(str)
s3=s3+','+s3.groupby(s3).cumcount().astype(str)
df1['df2'],df1['df3']=s1.isin(s2).astype(int),s1.isin(s3).astype(int)
df1
Out[308]: 
    Key   A   B  df2  df3
0  key1  a1  b1    1    1
1  key1  a1  b1    1    0
2  key1  a1  b2    0    1
3  key2  a2  b2    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a full outer join. For doing so you can use the merge() method with the how='outer' option ex:

```
df_1['df_1'] = 1
df_2['df_2'] = 1
result_df = df_1.merge(df_2, how='outer').merge(Base_df, how='outer')
```